# Ka relating to Dissociation of Weak acid and Water

Tags: equilibrium, water, significant-figures

I am studying $K_a$ currently and there is a passage in the book that doesn't appear to make sense.

It states that from the equation

$$\ce{HA <=> H+ + A-}$$

that $$K_a = \frac{[H^+][A^-]}{[HA]}$$

The following passage says `When dealing with weak acids, you can assume that dissociation of the acid is much greater than the dissociation of water.`

It continues to say that `you can assume all the H+ ions come from the acid.`

hence $$K_a = \frac{[H^+]^2}{[HA]}$$

What I don't understand is the dissociation of water.

The book gives the equation of dissociation of water as the following -

$$\ce{H_2O(l) + H_2O(l) <=> H3O+ + OH-}$$

but where does the H+ come from from this dissociation - it's made a Hydroxonium ion?

Is it because the $H_3O^+$ can act as the conjugate acid and release the proton?

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, water [autodissociates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-ionization_of_water) according to the equation $\ce{2H2O <=> H3O+ + OH-}$.

But I should point out that the equilibrium constant is written as though the concentration of water itself is a constant, so the reactions becomes:

$\ce{H2O <=> H+ + OH-}$.

and the equilibrium is expressed as:

$K_\rm{w} = 1\times10^{-14} = \ce{[H+][OH-]}$

The pH is $\text{-log}\ce{([H+])}$ thus the pH of pure water is 7.

This also has to do with significant figures. Few pKa's are known to better than two significant figures. So:

- For weak acid with pKa < 5 you can ignore water contribution.
- For acid with pKa > 9 you can assume all the  $\ce{H+}$ is from water and that all of the acid is essentially present as the HA form.
- For 9 > pKa > 5 you have to consider both ionization of the acid and water.

Answer (score 2):

I think MaxW's answer covers the gist of the question from the calculation side, but its also worth noting something else about your question. $\ce{H^+}$ and $\ce{H3O^+}$ are often used interchangeably for the acidic proton, but $\ce{H3O^+}$ is more accurate; free protons are unlikely to exist in solution. $\ce{H3O^+}$ is one example of how the proton could be passed into the solution and so is used to represent the general case of the proton being solvated by a water cluster. For more information on these water clusters, go the solvation section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydronium.